# How can I allow pages on CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I am trying to allow some pages in my project from Cake function beforeFilter, but it's not working at all. The only allowed page is the 'login' page. I am using this function on the controller 'PagesController':

```
public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();  
        $this->Auth->allow(array('login', 'definition'));
    }
```

Please, help me! I've started to learn CakePHP recently, so I'm having some problems with it. :\

Comment: You don't allow access to the login page - ever. Think about it, if the login page was protected, who could you ever login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the fuction name of pages controller in `$this->Auth->allow()`;

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();  
    $this->Auth->allow(array(
        'login', 
        'definition',
        'give here your pages controller function name'
        )
   );
}
```

Comment: `the fuction name of pages controller in` - it's called [display](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/src/Controller/PagesController.php#L38).